# Unable to create new notebook when Interpreter is created through Zeppelin API?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Use case: When we create new interpreter through Zeppelin API we are unable to create new notebook. Instead it's creating some garbage notebooks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McxD6.png)

Only after restarting Zeppelin service we are able to create new notebook and work on it.

Can someone help me to resolve above issue without restarting Zeppelin service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please embed the picture in the question.

Comment: Feel free to create JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN - please provide version information, etc.

Comment: Zeppelin version 0.8.2 installed in ubuntu 20.04